Changing Background of specific cell in ListView .NET MAUI
I have my ListView containing list of objects called "Item"
I want that once an Item is clicked, change it's background color to a different color.
My issue is that I can't access a specific cell. I can access the Item using list.selectedItem but not the cell containing him
            this.list = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Item>(Lists.Items),
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    Label nameLabel = Lists.settings.CreateLabel();


                    Label descriptionLabel = Lists.settings.CreateLabel();
                    Button addButton = new Button
                    {
                        Text = "+",
                        FontSize = 16,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Settings.LightModeColors[0]),
                        TextColor = Colors.Black,

                    };
                    Button deductButton = new Button
                    {
                        Text = "-",
                        FontSize = 16,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(Settings.DarkModeColors[0]),
                        TextColor = Colors.White,

                    };
                    Label quantityLabel=Lists.settings.CreateLabel("0");
                    nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(Item.Name));
                    descriptionLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(Item.Description));
                    addButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        quantityLabel.Text = "" + (int.Parse(quantityLabel.Text) + 1);
                        Debug.WriteLine(args.GetType());
                        AddItem("id");
                    };
                    deductButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        if (quantityLabel.Text != "0")
                        { 
                            
                            quantityLabel.Text = "" + (int.Parse(quantityLabel.Text) - 1);
                            DeductItem(nameof(Item.Id));
                        }
                    };

                    Grid templateLayout = new Grid
                    {
                        RowDefinitions =
                        {
                            new RowDefinition{Height=new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },
                        },
                        ColumnDefinitions =
                        {
                            new ColumnDefinition{Width=new GridLength(3,GridUnitType.Star) },
                            new ColumnDefinition{Width=new GridLength(2,GridUnitType.Star) },
                            new ColumnDefinition{Width=new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },
                            new ColumnDefinition{Width=new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },
                            new ColumnDefinition{Width=new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },

                        },
                    };
                    templateLayout.Add(nameLabel, 0, 0);
                    templateLayout.Add(descriptionLabel, 1, 0);
                    templateLayout.Add(addButton, 2, 0);
                    templateLayout.Add(quantityLabel, 3, 0);
                    templateLayout.Add(deductButton, 4, 0);
                    
                    return new ViewCell { View = templateLayout };
                })

            };


            list.ItemTapped += OnItemTapped;
        private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e) 
        {
            //list.SelectedItem = null;
            Debug.WriteLine(sender.GetType());
            Debug.WriteLine(((ListView)sender).SelectedItem.GetType());
            Debug.WriteLine(e.GetType());
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ItemIndex.GetType());
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Item.GetType());

        }

tried debugging to find the some type of View object inside listview

you should never try to directly modify the UI of a templated control.  Instead, bind the view property to a property of the model, and use a IValueConverter to set the color based on the value of the property

Do you use XAML to define the visual contents or only use C# code?

@LiqunShen-MSFT Only C#

You may try using Visual State to change the BackgroundColor of a SelectedItem, which I think is the most easiest way. But here I recommend using CollectionView instead of ListView, as CollectionView aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to ListView. (and for some reason, visual state not work in ListView)
Here is an example to add a Visual States in code behind.
this.list = new CollectionView()
{
    ItemsSource = items,
    SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single,
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        Label nameLabel = new Label();
        Label descriptionLabel = new Label();
        ...
        ...
        //Define Visual States here
        var vsgs = new VisualStateGroupList();
        var vsg = new VisualStateGroup() { Name = "CommonStates" };
        var vs_normal = new VisualState { Name = "Normal" };
        var vs_selected = new VisualState { Name = "Selected" };
        vs_normal.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Colors.White });
        vs_selected.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Colors.Green });
        vsg.States.Add(vs_normal);
        vsg.States.Add(vs_selected);
        vsgs.Add(vsg);

        Grid templateLayout = new Grid
        {
            ...
        };
        templateLayout.Add(nameLabel, 0, 0);
        ...
        templateLayout.Add(deductButton, 4, 0);

        //Set VisualStates on the Grid
        VisualStateManager.SetVisualStateGroups(templateLayout, vsgs);


        return templateLayout;
    })
};


Another option is that you could use data binding as Jason mentioned.
You could set the binding for BackgroundColor Property for Grid.
templateLayout.SetBinding(Grid.BackgroundColorProperty, nameof(Item.BgColor));

That means you have to add a new Property BgColor in the Item model. Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged,
public class Item :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    Color bgColor;
    public Color BgColor 
    { 
        get
        {
            return bgColor;
        }           
        set
        {
            bgColor = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(BgColor)));
        }                             
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}

Also, implement the ItemSelected Event Handler for ListView,
        this.list.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if(list.SelectedItem == item)
                {
                    item.BgColor = Colors.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.BgColor= Colors.White;
                }
            }
        };

which makes the selected item green and others white.
Hope it helps!

Ill Read about CollectionView and return an answer

Thanks for your response. Please let me know if you have any questions.
